Please help me understanding this property of finite maps
Question
I am reading Section 5.3 of Chapter 1 (pages 60-61) of Basic Algebraic Geometry I by Shafarevich. I do not understand some parts of this section, which I will detail below.
The content of the book is in the blockquotes. Thanks a lot for your help.
First, the book defines 'integral' as follows:

Let $A$ be a subring of ring $B$. An element $b\in B$ is called integral over $A$ if it satisfies an equation $$b^k+a_1b^{k-1}+\dots +a_k=0,$$ with $a_i \in A$. And $B$ is integral over $A$ if any $b\in B$ is integral over $A$.

I think the "$0$" on the right side of the equation $b^k+a_1b^{k-1}+\dots +a_k=0$ is the zero element of $B$, is it right?
Next, the book derives the definition of 'finite map' as follows:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be affine varieties and $f:X\to Y$ a regular map such that $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$. Then the pullback map $f^*$ defines an isomorphic inclusion $k[Y]\to k[X]$. We view $k[Y]$ as a subring of $k[X]$ by means of $f^*$. $f$ is called a finite map if $k[X]$ is integral over $k[Y]$.

By the definition, if $f$ is a finite map, then, for any $b\in k[X]$, there exist $a_i \in k[Y]$ such that $$b^k+a_1 b^{k-1}+\dots +a_k=0,$$ and the  "$0$" on the right side of the above equation is the zero element of $k[X]$? If it is, then the polynomial $$b^k+a_1 b^{k-1}+\dots +a_k,$$ is a zero polynomial of$k[Y]$, meaning that for any element $y\in Y$, the value of polynomial $$b^k+a_1 b^{k-1}+\dots +a_k,$$ at $y$ is zero (this zero is a real number of field $k$, is it correct?).
However, the book presents an opposite result, and this is where I got confused. It says:

Suppose that $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ and let $t_1,\dots ,t_n$ be the coordinates of $\mathbb{A}^n$ viewed as functions on $X$. It is enough to prove that any coordinate $t_i$ only takes a finite number of values on the set $f^{-1}(y)$. By definition $t_i$ satisfies an equation $t_i^k+a_1 t_i^{k-1}+\dots +a_k=0$ with $a_i \in k[Y]$. For $y \in Y$ and $x \in f^{-1}(y)$, we get an equation $$ t_i^k(x)+a_1(y)t_i^{k-1}(x)+\dots +a_k(y)=0 ,$$which has only a finite number of roots.

However, based on my  understanding, in the above equation, $$ \begin{array}{l}t_i^k(x)+a_1(y)t_i^{k-1}(x)+\dots +a_k(y)\\=t_i^k(x)+a_1(f(x))t_i^{k-1}(x)+\dots +a_k(f(x))\end{array} $$ is the zero polynomial in $k[X]$, implying that this equation could have infinitely many solutions.
Again, thanks a lot for figuring out which part I missed.
A Possible answer
Many thanks to @Piyo. I believe the following answer addresses what I missed. Please let me know if it is still incorrect. Thanks!
1
The elements of $k[X]$ are polynomials, we denote the 'variables' of these polynomials as $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$.
Similarly, the elements of $k[Y]$ are polynomials, we denote the 'variables' of these polynomials as $\eta_1, \dots, \eta_n$.
As the book says, $k[Y]$ can be viewed as a subset of $k[X]$ because of the pullback map $f^*$, in fact, for any polynomial $a(\eta_1,\dots,\eta_n)\in k[Y]$, it can be viewed as $a\circ f(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)\ \in k[X] $ (when considering their algebraic property?).
2
Because $f$ is a finite map, for any $t_i$, the  following equation holds. (This equation means its left side is the zero polynomial of $k[X]$).
$$ t_i^k +a_1 t_i^{k-1}+\dots + a_k = 0. $$
The left side of the above equation can be written with 'variables' as
$$ t_i^k(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n) +a_1(\eta_1,\dots,\eta_n) t_i^{k-1}(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)+\dots + a_k(\eta_1,\dots,\eta_n), $$
By the last section,  the above formula can be written as
$$ t_i^k(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n) +a_1\circ f(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n) t_i^{k-1}(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)+\dots + a_k\circ f(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n). $$
Since it is a zero polynomial, for any $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)\in X$
$$ t_i^k(x_1,\dots,x_n) +a_1\circ f(x_1,\dots,x_n) t_i^{k-1}(x_1,\dots,x_n)+\dots + a_k\circ f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0. $$
the value of the right side polynomial is $0$, this $0$ is an element of $k$.
3
For any $\bar y=(\bar y_1,\dots,\bar y_n)\in Y$($\bar y$ is the '$y$' in the book),
we know that $f^{-1}(\bar y)$ is a set. All we want is to prove that $f^{-1}(\bar y)$ is a finite set.
Let $\bar x=(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n)\in f^{-1}(\bar y)$, by the last section (both sides of the following equation are elements of $k$)
$$ t_i^k(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n) +a_1\circ f(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n) t_i^{k-1}(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n)+\dots + a_k\circ f(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n) = 0. $$
Because $\bar x=(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n)\in f^{-1}(\bar y)$
$$ t_i^k(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n) +a_1(\bar y_1,\dots,\bar y_n) t_i^{k-1}(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n)+\dots + a_k(\bar y_1,\dots,\bar y_n) = 0. $$
Clearly $t_i(\bar x_1,\dots,\bar x_n)\in k$ is the root of the following polynomial equation about $T$
$$ T^k+a_1(\bar y_1,\dots,\bar y_n) T^{k-1}+\dots +a_k(\bar y_1,\dots,\bar y_n)=0 $$
Denote the solution of the above equation as $Z$. We know that $Z \subset k$ and $Z$ is finite.
Therefore, every projection $t_i$ of  $f^{-1}(\bar y)$ is a set contains finite elements. Thus, $f^{-1}(\bar y)$ is finite.
The other question
There remains the other question (or I could just post a new question): What role do 'finite maps' play in algebraic geometry? Do they play the role of 'nice and frequently appearing maps,' like compact maps or smooth maps in real analysis?

We have a blockquote functionality here which you can use for quoted text. The markdown formatting for this is > quoted text here. I've made this upgrade for you this time.

Thanks a lot o7


I think the "$0$" on the right side of the equation $b^k+a_1b^{k−1}+\dotsb+a_k=0$ is the zero element of $B$, is it right?

Yes.

the "$0$" on the right side of the above equation is the zero element of $k[X]$?

Yes.

the polynomial $$b^k+a_1b^{k−1}+\dotsb+a_k,$$
is a zero polynomial of $k[Y]$, meaning that for any element $y\in Y$ the value of polynomial $$b^k+a_1b^{k−1}+\dotsb+a_k,$$
at $y$ is zero (this zero is a real number of field $k$, is it correct?)

This looks a little strange.
Since $b\in k[X]$, it is more natural to consider the values at $x\in X$, not at $y\in Y$.
In fact, it holds that for any $x\in X$ the value of $b^k+a_1b^{k-1}+\dotsb+a_k$ at $x$ is zero.
Here this zero is in the field $k$ as you wrote.

$$t^k_i(x)+a_1(y)t^{k−1}_i(x)+\dotsb+a_k(y)$$
is the zero polynomial in $k[X]$, implying that this equation could have infinitely many solutions.

This is not true.
Note that $t_i(x)$ is an element of the field $k$ because it is the value of $t_i$ at $x$, not the function $t_i\in k[X]$ itself.
Thus the possible $t_i(x)\in k$ are finitely many, as the book says.
